# How to get a CGPoint from a tapped location on a custom View When Voice Over Enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, accessibility

I am setting up my app to be compatible with Voice Over feature. I have a graph, I am getting single tap on the -accessibilitiHint(). I need to confirm the user action on double tap which the even can be obtained with accessibilityActivate(). The touch point needs to be retrieved on Single tap.

Now Is there any method to to get user touch point when single tap is performed on my View ?

Comment: in your gesture handler method write CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:yourView];

Answer (score 0):

For Objective C

Step 1:Add TapeGesture Recognizer to your View

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureHandler:)];
tapGesture.delegate = self;   
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Step 2: implement Gesture Delegate Method

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Step 3: implement Gesture Handler

```
- (void)tapGestureHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:yourView];
}
```

Comment: If I have added a single tap gesture recognizer to custom view, to fire the method on single tap the following things need to be done. 1) Retun NO from the method accessibilityActivate() [Default] 2) Double Tap on the view. (Which does not satisfy my requirement )